# Nesting jQuery functions within functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Below is the code I am working on

```
$("#firstnamesubmitbutton").click(function(){
  $(".hrmed").addClass("lineanimation", function(){

  $(".firstnamesection").addClass("animate fadeOut");
  $(".firstnamesection").addClass("hidden");
  $(".hrmed").removeClass("lineanimation");
  $(".lastnamesection").removeClass("hidden");
  alert("Code was executed");
  });  

});
```

I am trying to created a nested jQuery function so that the rest of the code is called after the "lineanimation" class has been added but when I run this code the "lineanimation" class is added and the rest of the commands are not executed. Can anyone help me understand the correct syntax to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need there to be a delay, then you'll have to use `setTimeout()`. The `.addClass()` method does not have a callback (your attempt) because it happens *instantly*. However by doing `.addClass()`, and then `removeClass()` three lines later, you'll never see the class get added.

Comment: I don't want the rest of the code to execute until after the animation contained in the class "lineanimation" has finished. The way you are suggesting the rest of the code will execute before the animation has finished, this i why I added the function to delay the rest of the code execution until after the animation has finished.

Comment: You should include that in your question. You cannot use a callback method with `addClass()`. Instead, add the class on one line. In the following line, do a `setTimeout()` with your current callback function as the first parameter, and the time (in milleseconds) of the animation as the second.

Comment: Sorry Tyler but how would that code look? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'd mentioned above, `.addClass()` is instant. As such, it does not take a callback method. Additionally, it has no way of inherently knowing the duration of your CSS transition.

Instead, you could use `setTimeout()`. It will execute a given function after waiting *X* milliseconds.

The first argument would be the function you've written in your question. The second parameter corresponds to the length of your CSS animation.

(For example, a `3s` animation would be `3000`.)

```js
$("#firstnamesubmitbutton").click(function() {
  var $hrmed = $(".hrmed");
  $hrmed.addClass("lineanimation");

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".firstnamesection").addClass("animate fadeOut hidden");
    $hrmed.removeClass("lineanimation");
    $(".lastnamesection").removeClass("hidden");
    console.log("Code was executed");
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.hrmed {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hrmed.lineanimation {
  background: blue;
  transition: background 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="firstnamesubmitbutton">Click me</button>
<div class="hrmed"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Editted**

```js
$("#firstnamesubmitbutton").click(function(){
  $('.hrmed').delay(1000).queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass('lineanimation').dequeue();
  }).delay(2000).queue(function () {
    $(".firstnamesection").addClass("animate fadeOut");
    $(".firstnamesection").addClass("hidden");
    $(".lastnamesection").removeClass("hidden");
    $(this).removeClass('lineanimation');
    alert("Code was executed");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.lineanimation {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="firstnamesubmitbutton">Click</button>
<div class="hrmed">
  <div class="firstnamesection">firstname</div>
  <div class="lastnamesection">lastname</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `if` statement does not make sense. You're adding the class, and then checking if it's been added on the next line. How would that ever be false?

Comment: I just missed his point, So he might look into queue and dequeue instead.

Comment: That's more on the right track, however you should spend some time explaining your answer, rather than just putting a block of code.